# Rails: How do I reset models and migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, database-migration, rails-migrations

I've been working with Rails and of course have learned quite a bit since I started.  I'm wanting to keep a lot of my files I've made but I'm wanting to recreate many of my models.  Since I wasn't concerned with losing information in my database, I ran `rake db:drop:all` to get rid of all my tables and data.  However I noticed I still have all my migration files in my folder `db\migrate`.  How should I handle these? Do I just leave them and make changes to my models now or should I delete them in some way. Finally, are there any other files that might still be lingering around that I need to delete/attend to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `rake db:drop:all` will only clean your database.

If you plan on changing your models and you think your migrations will not reflect your data model anymore, simply delete them.

You might want to clean the file `db/schema.rb` too

You might want to checkout rails migration guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Thanks! If anyone wants to know exactly what I did, I did the `rake db:drop:all`; followed that up with creating a new migration file with all my tables and indexes the way I wanted them. Then ran `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`, following that up with manually editing the model files. Anyways thanks again!